# Can not get input value using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can not get the input field value which contains Date of birth from calendar using c# asp.net.I am explaining my code below.

`index.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DoctorSignUp.aspx.cs" Inherits="Odiya_Doctor_Client.DoctorSignUp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   <div class="bannertopheader clearfix"></div>
   <div class="col-md-6 bmargindiv1">
      <label for="dateofbirth" accesskey="D"><span class="required">*</span> Date of Birth</label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" name="dateofbirth" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" onchange="selectGender('dob');"></asp:TextBox>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12 bmargindiv1">
       <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" class="button" ID="doctorDetails" OnClick="doctorDetails_Click" />
   </div>
</asp:Content>
```

`Site.Master`:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Odiya_Doctor_Client.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Welcome to Odia Doctor</title>
    <!--<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="author" content="odiadoctor" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/apple_icons_57x57.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple_icons_72x72.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple_icons_114x114.png" />
        <!--/ metas -->

        <!-- styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layerslider.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fullwidth/skin.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/owl.carousel.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/color-blue.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/intlTelInput.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/daterangepicker-bs3.css" />
        <!--/ styles -->

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div class="page">

   </div>
   </form>
   <!-- scripts -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.migrate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flot.categories.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/greensock.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/layerslider.transitions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.velocity.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>        
    <!-- Superscrollorama -->       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.superscrollorama.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/TimelineMax.min.js"></script>
    <!--/ Superscrollorama -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.tabs.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-tabs-rotate.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.accordion.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tweet.js"></script>
    <!-- EASYPIECHART -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easypiechart.js"></script>
    <!--/ EASYPIECHART -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/intlTelInput.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/preloader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment.js"></script>
        <script src="js/daterangepicker.js"></script>
        <!--/ scripts -->
        <script >
            $("#MainContent_mobilenumber").intlTelInput({
        });
        $(function () {
            $('#MainContent_txtDOB').daterangepicker({
                singleDatePicker: true,
                showDropdowns: true,
                minDate: '01/01/1980',
                maxDate: '12/31/2015'
            });
        });
        $(function () {
            //Hide label after 5 secs
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("[id$=textInfo]").fadeOut("slow");
            }, 5000);
        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.aspx.cs:

```
namespace Odiya_Doctor_Client
{
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void doctorDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write(txtDOB.Text.Trim());
        }
    }
}
```

When user is giving any input to `DOB` field and clicks on submit button,It should display but the line inside `doctorDetails_Click` is showing null.I need here when user will insert any value that should retrieve in code backend page after submit button click.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
Response.Write(txtDOB.Text.Trim());
```

to

```
Response.Write(txtDOB.Text);
```

Comment: @ Rishad : But you line is showing this error.`Error 86 'string' does not contain a definition for 'toString' and no extension method 'toString' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `

Comment: @ Rishad : Initially it will remain empty.When user will select date from calender and then click on submit button.

Comment: @ Rishad : Again Issue is there after implementing your updated line.